# Back button does not work

Tags: html, css, browser

I am working on developing an Intranet for my business, however, whenever I try to hit the back button on any browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE), it shows the page you want to go back to, but then jumps back to the previous page you were at.  I'm using a full screen navigation that uses div ID's and CSS to work, but I'm not sure if that's the issue or not.  When I click on the Nav button, the URL comes up with this:

http://portalnew:10080/#sidebar

Then I click to a different page then try to go back and it won't go back.

Any suggestions?  Let me know if you need to see the code.

PS: I got the code from codepen.io  http://codepen.io/AbdelrahmanMohsen/pen/PwVgMb

```
`<div class="stuck-head">
  <a class="nav-btn" id="nav-open" href="#sidebar"><span>menu</span></a>
</div>

<div id="menu">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">| &nbsp; Home &nbsp; |</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">| &nbsp; Oracle &nbsp; |</a></li>
      <li><a href="it_support.html">| &nbsp; IT Support &nbsp; |</a></li>
      <li><a href="online_forms.html">| &nbsp; Online Forms &nbsp; |</a></li>
      <li><a href="human_resources.html">| &nbsp; Human Resouces &nbsp; |</a></li>     
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Could you post more relevant code? like the actual "back" button you are mentioning?

Comment: It's just the native back button included in all browsers.

Comment: I found out what was causing this issue.  It was an iFrame that was in another part of my code.